# JQuery mobile external links issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, hyperlink

I am a newbie to the jQuery mobile platform.

I am facing a problem. I have an About Us page wherein I have a link, say google.com
When I run this page on any of the browsers, it is working fine. But when I make a build of this and deploy it on ipad, it is not working.

I am very much confused as to why is this happening.

Following is my code snippet

```
<h3 align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="ui-link-inherit ui-link" target="_new">www.google.com</a></h3>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i know this is old but its `<a href="link here" target="new">`

or

```
<a href="link here" target="_blank">
```

also if its jquery mobile, you have to add a "rel=external" to the link.

so it would be `<a href="link here" rel="external">`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `target="_blank"` instead of `target="_new"` The last one doesn't exist.